# Is there a way to check if requiredResourceAccess has been granted on an application via the Graph API?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am registering an application in Azure AD using the Graph API (via the NodeJS SDK) I need to wait until a site admin has granted access to the RequiredResources for the new application.  How can I check if that access has been granted to the application via the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can Check this states. [Microsoft Graph REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/) provides this functionality.

In your case you can do this by calling [privilegedApproval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/privilegedapproval?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0) API which allow you to check following consent:

> **pending, approved, denied, aborted, canceled**

You could use this API *[Get privilegedApproval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/privilegedapproval-get?view=graph-rest-beta)*

> **Note :** APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not
>   supported.

For more details you could refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/privilegedapproval?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: @MrDaveM check out your way around. If you have any more query feel free to ask here in comments. Thank you